# errorText flutter issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I build the widget with `TextField` but error text is shows inside the field.

[image]

The widget is:

```
child: TextField(
    maxLines: 1,
    controller: textEditingController,
    style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: ConstantData.fontFamily,
        color: ConstantData.textColor,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        fontSize: fontSize),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: ConstantWidget.getWidthPercentSize(context, 2)),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: 'name',
        errorText: 'errorText',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: ConstantData.fontFamily,
            color: ConstantData.textColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: fontSize)),
  ),
```

Where is my mistake to show the text inside of field, not below them?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have wrapped the `TextField` with a `Container` of grey color.

Please remove it and add `fillColor` and `filled` properties to the `InputDecoration()` to color the `TextField`.

For example:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    ...
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.grey, // Any color you want
    ...
)
```